# How do i make audio pause in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, pause

I tried making a visual novel for learning. I can't figure out how to stop/pause my audio file in javascript/jQuery.

I want to play and pause different music if a character appears. They appear if the counter has a certain value - the music has to do the same. The music starts playing when the `data-current` is at `2` but doesn't pause/stop with the method `pause()` at `data-current == 5`

How can I solve this problem?

```js
$('#textbox').click(function () {
  // ...
  var musics = ['MagicalForest.mp3', 'bunnymusic.mp3', ]
  var IntroAudio = new Audio(musics[0]);
  var bunnyAudio = new Audio(musics[1]);

  if ($('#textbox').attr('data-current') == 2) {
    IntroAudio.play();
  }

  if ($('#textbox').attr('data-current') == 5) {
    IntroAudio.pause();
    bunnyAudio.play();
  };
};
```

Comment: i already checked for errors, there is none :(

Comment: In that case I have updated your snippet to remove the error as you must have created the issue when copying the code over

Comment: yes i had many problems by copying the code here... i had to type almost everything new cause the preview showed me all code in one line, without any paragraphs...

Comment: You can use the snippet editor to past code and format it more easily. To do that click the `[<>]` button, or press CTRL+M, when editing the question

Comment: thanks :) but i still don´t get why the .pause( ) method doesn´t work, the .play() method works fine...

Comment: Without seeing a working example it's going to be almost impossible for anyone to debug this. I'd suggest you put some breakpoints and/or `console.log()` statements in to the code to double check the logic flows as you are expecting.

Comment: i did this with alert(5) if the data-current is at 5. It works, also the bunnymusic.mp3 starts at data-current 5... the only thing that doesn´t want to work is the IntroAudio.pause() method. The two audiofiles play at the same time when data-current reaches value 5 but i want the Intromusic to stop at this value...